# MySQL Order Previous 6 Months In Reverse

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the below MySQL query that outputs months and SUM of value properly but I want to order the date for the previous 6 months data in reverse rolling format so it would be Feb, Jan, Dec, Nov, Oct, Sep.  However this range will change every month so not sure that `field()` function would apply in an `ORDER BY`?

```
SELECT month(c.date) AS month_num, monthname(c.date) AS month, SUM(value) AS total
FROM commissions c
WHERE c.date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 MONTH AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY month(c.date)
```

**Result:**

```
| month_num | month     | total   | 
|-----------|-----------|---------|
| 1         | January   | 45198   | 
| 2         | February  | 95661   | 
| 9         | September | 8373    |
| 10        | October   | 5356    |
| 11        | November  | 4745    |
| 12        | December  | 4830    |
```

Need this to be reverse rolling format Feb, Jan, Dec, Nov, Oct, Sep.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is will help

```
SELECT month(c.date) AS month_num, monthname(c.date) AS month, SUM(value) AS 
total
FROM commissions c
WHERE c.date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 MONTH AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY month(c.date)
ORDER BY c.date DESC
```